# Copy file as another name if file exist

Tags: batch-file, cmd, backup, xcopy

I want to copy specific file from pc to usb

my code :

```
  xcopy /H /Y /C /R "C:\image1.jpeg" "G:\backup\image.jpeg"
```

i want to do following : 
if G:\backup\image1.jpeg exist, copy image.jpeg as image2.jpeg (or as another name),

if image2.jpeg exist, copy as image3.jpeg and ect..

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Did you really mean `xcopy /H /Y /C /R "C:\image.jpeg" "G:\backup\image1.jpeg"`? Your question doesn't quite make sense the way it is written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume your source name is "image.jpeg" and your destination has the appended suffix.

I recommend putting a dot before the appended suffix to make it clear where the original name ends and the suffix begins. Your original name could already have a number at the end.

Here is a crude but very effective brute force method that supports up to 100 copies. Obviously the upper limit can easily be increased.

```
call :backup "c:\image.jpeg"
exit /b

:backup
for /l %%N in (1 1 100) do (
  if not exist "G:\backup\%~n1.%%N.%~x1" (
    echo F|xcopy %1 "G:\backup\%~n1.%%N.%~x1" >nul
  )
  exit /b
)
```

But there is a potential problem. Suppose image.1.txt and image.2.txt already exist, but then you delete image.1.txt. The next time you backup it will re-create image.1.txt and then you might think that image.2.txt is the most recent backup.

The following can be used to always create a new backup with the number suffix 1 greater than the largest existing suffix, even if there are wholes in the numbers.

```
@echo off
call :backup "c:\image.jpeg"
exit /b

:backup
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set /a n=0
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%A in (
  'dir /b "g:\backup\%~n1.*%~x1"^|findstr /rec:"\.[0-9][0-9]*\%~x1"'
) do for %%B in ("%%~nA") do (
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set "n2=%%~xB"
  set "n2=!n2:~1!"
    if !n2! gtr !n! (
    for %%N in (!n2!) do (
      endlocal
      set "n=%%N"
    )
  ) else endlocal
)
set /a n+=1
echo F|xcopy %1 "g:\backup\%~n1.%n%%~x1" >nul
```